# assign delegate to view from story board swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates, storyboard

I am trying to assign the delegate to the view controller so i can use that class delegate in my current class.I want to assign the delegate to the **VC**
i am using the following code

```
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popUp")


    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200 , 300)

    let popoverMenuViewController = vc.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the delegate correctly.

Next you need to implement the delegate methods that you want to use in your view controller. First, you have to have your view controller conform to the delegate protocol:

```
class MyViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    // The rest of the class here.
```

Then, implement the methods that you want to use from the protocol, for example:

```
func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverVC: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
    // The rest of the function here.
```